# iOS Simulator - how to test older (32-bit) devices?

Tags: ios, xamarin, ios-simulator, 32bit-64bit

Easy question. Is it possible to test 32-bit devices (iPhone 5/5c, iPad 2, etc.) on the iOS Simulator since the latest (11) iOS/SDK has been released? Since my budget is about $2, just buying a used one isn't currently an option (unfortunately). Are there options out there for the simulator?

Thanks for putting up with the noob question,

E

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XCode --> Preferences --> Components will allow you do download simulator images for older versions of iOS

Comment: Genius... thanks! That's what I get for staying inside Visual Studio and not digging around in XCode. Now I'm running into the issue of the app working fine on the older device simulators, but unable to test it on a real device. Budget coding is rough...